# PostgreSQL Null breaks lists when looking for NOT IN

Tags: postgresql

I think this might be a PostgreSQL bug but I'm posting it here in case I'm just missing something. When my WHERE clause has a `NOT IN ()` clause, having `null` in the list makes the clause no longer truthy. Below is a dumbed down example of my issue.

```
=# select 1 where 1 not in (1);
 ?column? 
----------
(0 rows)

=# select 1 where 1 not in (2);
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)

=# select 1 where 1 not in (null);
 ?column? 
----------
(0 rows)

=# select 1 where 1 not in (null, 2);
 ?column? 
----------
(0 rows)

=# select 1 where 1 not in (2, null);
 ?column? 
----------
(0 rows)

=# select 1 where 1 not in (2, 3);
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

So `where 1 not in (1)` returns 0 rows as expected since `1` is in the list, `where 1 not in (2)` returns 1 row as expected since `1` is not in the list, but `where 1 not in (null)` returns 0 rows even though `1` is not in the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a PostgreSQL bug.

The problem is that [`NOT IN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.15) is just the short version for testing all inequalities one by one.

`1 NOT IN (null, 2)` is equivalent to:

```
1 <> null
AND
1 <> 2
```

However, `NULL` is a special value, so `1 <> null` is itself `NULL` (not `TRUE`). See the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html):

> Do not write expression = NULL because NULL is not “equal to” NULL. (The null value represents an unknown value, and it is not known whether two unknown values are equal.)

As far as I know that's the standard SQL behaviour.

PostgreSQL has an additional keyword to check whether a value is different from null:

`1 IS DISTINCT FROM NULL` would be `TRUE`.

Comment: I'm glad I asked here then. I figured it was either a bug or I was missing something crucial about how `NOT IN` works.

Comment: *"As far as I know that's the standard SQL behaviour."* indeed SQL 2003 defines  *"4.6.1 Comparison and assignment of booleans
All boolean data type values and SQL truth values are mutually comparable and assignable. The value true is greater than the value false , and **any comparison involving the null value or an unknown truth value will return an unknown result**"* That also means the optimizer can directly preprocess`1 <> null` with `null` and replace `null AND
1 <> 2` also with `null`.. Not sure if PostgreSQL optimizier does this kind of preprocessing..

Comment: @RaymondNijland: yes, the optimizer replaces `1 <> null` (or `column <> null`)  with `false` (you will see a line with  `One-Time Filter: false` in the execution plan)

Comment: Great i would expected it from the PostgreSQL optimizer @a_horse_with_no_name